# Identifying a theorem (or class of theorems) in commutative algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and for all $(i,j) \in \mathbb{E}_n^2$ ($\mathbb{E}_n=\{1,2,...,n\}$), $P_{ij}:V\to V$ is a linear map. Suppose moreover that...

1) $\forall (i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2)\in \mathbb{E}_n^4$:
\begin{equation}
P_{i_1j_1}\circ P_{i_2j_2} = P_{i_2j_2} \circ P_{i_1j_1}.
\end{equation}

2) $\{v_j \in V\}_{1\leq j \leq n}$ obey the following set of equations
\begin{equation}
\forall i \in \mathbb{E}_n:\, \sum_{j=1}^n P_{ij}v_j = 0.
\end{equation}
Then $\forall j \in \mathbb{E}_n$
\begin{equation}
(\det P) v_j = 0
\end{equation}
where $P$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with entries $P_{ij}$ and $\det P$ has the same combinatorial structure as the usual determinant, yet with all multiplications replaced by map compositions.

**Question**: What name(s) is given to this type of result in the mathematical literature? Are there short, elegant proofs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be derived from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem for commutative rings.

Condition 1 says that the unital $\mathbb F$-algebra $R$ generated by the $P_{ij}$ is a commutative ring.

The Cayley-Hamilton theorem says that for any $P\in R^{n\times n},$ if we define a polynomial $p$ over $R$ by $p(\lambda)=\det(\lambda-P),$ then $p(P)=0\in R^{n\times n}.$

Writing $*$ for the action of $R^{n\times n}$ on $V^n,$ if $P*v=0$ we get $$0*v=p(P)*v=p(0)*v=\det(-P)*v.$$
where in the second equality I am using the fact that the $P*v,P^2*v,\dots$ terms vanish.